# Wrong File System Size in Conky

Tags: conky

I installed Conky but it shows wrong size in the file system. I only have an HDD 1T and Conky says I use 8.4G out of 40G. What are those 40G? Why doesn't it says the right size? The configuration for the file system is the following.

```
$color${fs_used /} / ${fs_size /}
```

The output of `df -h` is the following.

[image]

Comment: And what would the right size be?  Don't you have any partitions? The size of `/` is the size of the `/` partition, not of the entire drive. Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `df -h`.

Comment: @terdon I edited my question.

Comment: See the lines for `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4`. The main part of the drive space is in `/dev/sda4`, your `/home` partition.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conky object you are using gives you the size of the disk partition mounted at `/`. In your case, that is 41G of which you are using 8.4G. So the conky output is correct.

You have partitioned your hard drive into at least three partitions. `sda1` is your `/boot` and `sda3` is `/`. Presumably, you also have `sda2` but it looks like it isn't mounted.

Comment: I used the command again that is the whole image. I didn't cropped it. So where is sda2? Is this weird?

Comment: @Adam no, not weird, it's probably just not mounted. Use `lsblk` or `blkid` or `sudo parted -l` to see all your partitions.

Answer (score 0):

in case you have multiple drives, then the totals will likely be wrong. I ended up with this code to get correct results in human readable format :

```
df -B1 | grep '^/dev/[hs]d' | awk '{s+=$3} END {print s}' | numfmt --to=iec-i
```

(you need to install `numfmt`)